# Kubernetes dashboard - ServiceUnavailable (503 error)

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard

I am a Kubernetes newbie. I am trying to setup a Kubernetes cluster on AWS using kops. I was successfully able to setup the cluster. However, I am not able to access the Dashboard UI. (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#accessing-the-dashboard-ui)

When I access the master node, I see the following error:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"kubernetes-dashboard\"",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}
```

I see the status of the dashboard as CrashLoopBackOff. (Please note: I have removed the names of the other pods in the following log)

```
~$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                    READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-4167803980-vnx3k                   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   6          6m

$ kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-4167803980-vnx3k --namespace=kube-system
2017/09/25 17:50:37 Using in-cluster config to connect to apiserver
2017/09/25 17:50:37 Using service account token for csrf signing
2017/09/25 17:50:37 No request provided. Skipping authorization
2017/09/25 17:50:37 Starting overwatch
2017/09/25 17:50:37 Successful initial request to the apiserver, version: v1.7.2
2017/09/25 17:50:37 New synchronizer has been registered: kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder-kube-system. Starting
2017/09/25 17:50:37 Starting secret synchronizer for kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder in namespace kube-system
2017/09/25 17:50:37 Initializing secret synchronizer synchronously using secret kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder from namespace kube-system
2017/09/25 17:50:37 Initializing JWE encryption key from synchronized object
2017/09/25 17:50:37 Creating in-cluster Heapster client
2017/09/25 17:50:37 Serving securely on HTTPS port: 8443
2017/09/25 17:50:37 open /certs/dashboard.crt: no such file or directory
```

I would sincerely appreciate any help/suggestions to get the dashboard running. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you install the dashboard? looks like its not able find the certificate file.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used the command on this page: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#accessing-the-dashboard-ui. I ran the following command: kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your using latest dashboard, looks like it required SSL certificate. try with 1.6.3 it will work with-out SSL cert.

I am running this version in my cluster.

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v1.6.3/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

**Helm command to install dashboard**

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding add-on-cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin  --serviceaccount=kube-system:default
helm install stable/kubernetes-dashboard  --name kubernetes-dashboard --namespace  kube-system --debug
helm install stable/heapster  --namespace  kube-system
```

Comment: You are a life-saver!! I have been struggling with this the entire day. Thank you. (Do you recommend any other tools to install with the dashboard, such as Grafana, Weave, etc?)

Comment: I use heapster along with dashboard. I will install these using helm. let me add the helm commands.

Comment: That would be really helpful! Thanks so much.